# 入力情報をデータベース（ＡＣＣＥＳＳ）へ登録したい

Tags: untagged

Ｗｅｂ画面にＡＣＣＥＳＳからＳＱＬ文で構成されたプルダウンリストが２つと、べた打ちで構成されたプルダウンリストを１つ作りました。そのプルダウンリストで選択したものを、データベースへ登録したいのですが、期待通りに動きません。
・ＡＣＣＥＳＳにある情報からＳＱＬによってプルダウンリストを構成しているので、ＡＣＣＥＳＳの接続はできています。
・選択された３つを変数pstrItem１，pstrItem２，pstrItem３に入れています。それはプルダウンリストの３つを選択後、登録ボタンを押した後、「本当に以下の情報で登録しますか？」という画面で出力が確認できています。
例えですが、テーブル名が個人情報、フィールド３つが性別（pstrItem１）、年齢（pstrItem２）、住んでいる県（pstrItem３）とします。
テーブル名はTABLENAMEにほかの箇所で代入しています。
それを踏まえて、以下のプログラムを見てください。

```
Sub Setsql_Insert()
DbCon_SQL = "INSERT INTO" & TABLENAME & "("
DbCon_SQL = DbCon_SQL & "性別,年齢,住んでいる県"
DbCon_SQL = DbCon_SQL & ")VALUES("
DbCon_SQL = DbCon_SQL & com.Ex_SQLDecode(com.chrRep(pstrItem1))
DbCon_SQL = DbCon_SQL & "," com.Ex_SQLDecode(com.chrRep(pstrItem2))
DbCon_SQL = DbCon_SQL & "," com.Ex_SQLDecode(com.chrRep(pstrItem3))
DbCon_SQL = DbCon_SQL & )"
```

というＳＱＬのインサート文を用いたものです。
これを

```
Call Setsql_Insert()
```

で呼び出して登録させようとしていましたが、データベース（ＡＣＣＥＳＳ）へは一向に登録できず。。。

元々他の人が作ったプログラムを改善、アップデートという形で改良していて、私自身まだＡＳＰやＳＱＬに関してあまり知識がない状態で作っているので、質問の内容も分からないかもしれませんが、宜しくお願いいたします。追加の説明など必要な情報があれば随時追加していくので、コメントの方宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: `Setsql_Insert`は、`DbCon_SQL`にINSERT文を設定しているだけに思います。昔ながらのASPであれば、ADODBなどを利用していると思います。その場合、`ADODB.Connection`オブジェクトの`Execute`メソッドにINSERT文を渡すと思います。`DbCon_SQL`は `Execute`メソッドに渡されているでしょうか?

Comment: 会社のプログラムで持ち帰れなかったので、今すぐには確認できないのですが、可能性は十分にあるかもしれないです。もし、DbCon_SQLがExecuteメソッドに渡せていない場合はどう渡せばよいのでしょうか。（初心者ですいません；

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/asp/ado_add.asp の下段にあるような形で、`conn.Execute sql ...`とします。

Comment: ふむふむ。。。ありがとうございます！明日早速試してみます。

Answer (score 0):

コードが正確ではないとのことですので、検討違いかもしれませんが、
DbCon_SQLの連結部分(5,6行目)は以下のように修正しないと、文字列の連結できません。
現在のSQLでエラーが発生していないか確認したほうが良いと思います。

```
DbCon_SQL = "INSERT INTO" & TABLENAME & "("
DbCon_SQL = DbCon_SQL & "性別,年齢,住んでいる県"
DbCon_SQL = DbCon_SQL & ")VALUES("
DbCon_SQL = DbCon_SQL & com.Ex_SQLDecode(com.chrRep(pstrItem1))
DbCon_SQL = DbCon_SQL & "," & com.Ex_SQLDecode(com.chrRep(pstrItem2))
DbCon_SQL = DbCon_SQL & "," & com.Ex_SQLDecode(com.chrRep(pstrItem3))
DbCon_SQL = DbCon_SQL & )"
```

Comment: 改善してみましたが、うまくいきませんでした。

Comment: 他のプログラムを参照したところ、作られたSQL文の関数は、Function ExecSQL(ByRef obj As Object)という関数の中で呼び出されていました。このFunctionの関数？はCall ExecSQL()で呼び出すと、式はメソッドではありませんと、エラーが出るんですけど、この関数はどうしたらうまく呼び出せますか？

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/calling-sub-and-function-procedures#function-プロシージャを呼び出すときのかっこの使用 にあるよう呼び出せます。